# Scope - How to return errors from laravel excel import?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, scope, laravel-excel

I'm using [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) for importing some data into my laravel app.

I'm looping trought the rows of the excel, validating the data and then save it, but if I got a validation error I want to return the $error variable from outside the Excel::load() function. Is it possible?

```
 public function import()
 {
     Excel::load(Input::file('excelFile'), function ($reader) {
                foreach ($reader->toArray() as $row) {
                   if($everythingOK){
                     //do stuff
                    } else {
                        $errors[] = 'error';
                    }
                }
            });
     return $errors;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create the array beforehand, then pass it through your function with the `&` to be able to use it in place.

```
public function import()
{
    $errors = [];
    Excel::load(Input::file('excelFile'), function ($reader) use (&$errors) {
        foreach ($reader->toArray() as $row) {
            if($everythingOK){
                //do stuff
            } else {
                $errors[] = 'error';
            }
        }
    });
    return $errors;
}
```

Otherwise, you can return `$errors` within your `load()` function. Just make sure you declare it before your foreach, so that it has something to pass back if there are no errors.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually hitting the else?

Comment: Never mind, I see. You need to add the `&` to `$errors`, so that it will pass it back through. I've updated my answer.

Comment: After wasting too much time, I have finally able to solve it.. +10 for your answer.. :D